# How to group migrations by year/version?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I realized that with time there is more and more migrations in migration folder. So I want to group those migration by year, application version, feature. For example there could be folders:
migrations/v23.02/
migrations/v23.01/
migrations/v22.04/
And this version/year/feature name would be stored inside app.confi.

I know that migration folder can be changed, but I want to know how to do it with way when I will be able to setup whole database without changing this value form first to latest one. So when I will run 'update-database' for the first time on db-server and in my configuration will be value 'v23.01', in fact I want to run migrations from 'v22.04', 'v23.01', 'v23.2' folders.

I how there is DbMigrationsConfiguration but I'm not sure hot to setup it to handle multiple folders for one context.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom IDbMigrationsConfiguration implementation:

```
public class CustomDbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public string MigrationVersion { get; set; }

    public CustomDbMigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        // Set any other configurations here if needed
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        // Other configuration settings...
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<string> GetMigrations()
    {
        // Get the base migrations from the base implementation
        var migrations = base.GetMigrations().ToList();

        // Load migrations from the version/year/feature folder based on the MigrationVersion
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MigrationVersion))
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // Change this to your migrations assembly

            var versionYearFeatureFolder = Path.Combine("migrations", MigrationVersion);

            if (assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Any(r => r.Contains(versionYearFeatureFolder)))
            {
                var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
                    .Where(r => r.Contains(versionYearFeatureFolder))
                    .OrderBy(r => r);

                migrations.AddRange(resourceNames);
            }
        }

        return migrations;
    }
}
```

In your application configuration, store the MigrationVersion value:
In the appsettings.json (or web.config depending on your project type), add a property for MigrationVersion:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "YourConnectionStringHere"
  },
  "MigrationVersion": "v23.02"
}
```

Initialize the CustomDbMigrationsConfiguration in the DbContext class:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext() : base("Default")
    {
        var migrationVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MigrationVersion"];
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDbContext, CustomDbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDbContext>>()
        {
            MigrationVersion = migrationVersion
        });
    }
}
```

With this setup, when you run update-database or perform database initialization, the migrations from the specified version/year/feature folder will be loaded and applied based on the value of MigrationVersion in your configuration. This allows you to organize your migrations in a more structured manner and apply only the migrations related to a specific version.

Comment: All this is "classic" EF6 approach, not applicable to EF Core, since none of these concepts exists there.